# Is It possible to unify queries generated by findby spring data

Tags: hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have an Entity Class like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="app_user_role")
public class AppUserRole implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private AppUserRolePK id;

    //uni-directional many-to-one association to App
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_app", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private App app;

    //uni-directional many-to-one association to Role
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_role", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Role role;

    //uni-directional many-to-one association to User
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_user", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private User user;

}
```

Then, call to the next method:

```
List<AppUserRole> appUserRoles= appUserRoleRepository.findByAppAndUser(app, user);
```

then, it generates the next queries:

```
Hibernate: select appuserrol0_.id_app as id_app1_2_, appuserrol0_.id_role as id_role2_2_, appuserrol0_.id_user as id_user3_2_, appuserrol0_.state as state4_2_ from security.app_user_role appuserrol0_ left outer join security.app app1_ on appuserrol0_.id_app=app1_.id left outer join security.user user2_ on appuserrol0_.id_user=user2_.id where app1_.id=? and user2_.id=?
Hibernate: select app0_.id as id1_0_0_, app0_.app as app2_0_0_, app0_.descr as descr3_0_0_ from security.app app0_ where app0_.id=?
Hibernate: select role0_.id as id1_4_0_, role0_.id_app as id_app3_4_0_, role0_.role as role2_4_0_, app1_.id as id1_0_1_, app1_.app as app2_0_1_, app1_.descr as descr3_0_1_ from security.role role0_ left outer join security.app app1_ on role0_.id_app=app1_.id where role0_.id=?
Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_5_0_, user0_.mail as mail2_5_0_, user0_.password as password3_5_0_, user0_.username as username4_5_0_ from security.user user0_ where user0_.id=?
```

It have generated multiple queries separated, 
How to unify this queries in only one query?

Consider the next method have generated only one query:

```
AppUserRolePK appUserRolePK = new AppUserRolePK(app.getId(), role.getId(), user.getId() );
AppUserRole appUserRole1 = appUserRoleRepository.findOne(appUserRolePK);
```

query generated:

```
Hibernate: select appuserrol0_.id_app as id_app1_2_0_, appuserrol0_.id_role as id_role2_2_0_, appuserrol0_.id_user as id_user3_2_0_, appuserrol0_.state as state4_2_0_, app1_.id as id1_0_1_, app1_.app as app2_0_1_, app1_.descr as descr3_0_1_, role2_.id as id1_4_2_, role2_.id_app as id_app3_4_2_, role2_.role as role2_4_2_, app3_.id as id1_0_3_, app3_.app as app2_0_3_, app3_.descr as descr3_0_3_, user4_.id as id1_5_4_, user4_.mail as mail2_5_4_, user4_.password as password3_5_4_, user4_.username as username4_5_4_ from security.app_user_role appuserrol0_ left outer join security.app app1_ on appuserrol0_.id_app=app1_.id left outer join security.role role2_ on appuserrol0_.id_role=role2_.id left outer join security.app app3_ on role2_.id_app=app3_.id left outer join security.user user4_ on appuserrol0_.id_user=user4_.id where appuserrol0_.id_app=? and appuserrol0_.id_role=? and appuserrol0_.id_user=?
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the regular behavior when you have mapped objects (loaded eager, what's the default for `@ManyToOne`).

With the first query in your example the identifiers of the mapped objects are received:

```
appuserrol0_.id_app as id_app1_2_, appuserrol0_.id_role as id_role2_2_, appuserrol0_.id_user as id_user3_2_,
```

The following queries are fetching every object itself with it's values (needed to satisfy the mapped fetch strategy) if they are not already available in the current persistence context. If they already exist in the (first level) cache, no additional selects would be needed.

If you want to override this behavior, write the HQL on your own, you can also do that on the Spring Data JPA repository using the `@Query` annotation:

```
@Query("FROM AppUserRole aur JOIN FETCH aur.app a JOIN FETCH aur.user u JOIN FETCH aur.role r WHERE a =:app AND u =:user")
Set<AppUserRole> findByAppAndUser(@Param("app") App app, @Param("user") User user);
```

Just keep in mind that you will lose all advantages of the lazy loading approach when you are using this query with the `JOIN FETCH` statement.

Comment: thanks, JOIN FETCH is the answer.
I have been investigating over first level cache with fetch mode but  I have not found examples,

Comment: http://javarevisited.blogspot.de/2017/03/difference-between-first-and-second-level-cache-in-Hibernate.html?m=1

Comment: You are welcome. Basically the first level cache stores already queried entities as long as the current persistence context / session is open, see the link in my previous comment. When an entity is available in this cache and it's again looked up (by identifer) there is no need to hit the database again. And I also corrected a small copy and paste issue in my code snippet :)